# Sort JSON alphabetically

Tags: jquery, json

I have a JSON object generated based on data stored in a table. I then need to be able to sort it in different ways, but when I do `JSON.stringify(array)` and try to sort from there it doesn't work. When I try to just do `array.sort();` it will change the order, but ultimately doesn't work. I don't have much experience with JSON and how to operate it so I'm not sure what else to try. After sorting it I need to go through and rewrite the table with the selected category in alphabetical order.

The JSON looks like this:

```
var arr = [{
"Functional Category":"T-Shirt",
"Brand Name":"threadless",
"When Obtained":"Last 3 Months",
"How Obtained":"Purchased",
"How Often Worn":"Monthly",
"Where It's Made":"India",
"Has a Graphic":"Yes"}]
```

I have a fiddle setup here: http://jsfiddle.net/Skooljester/88HVZ/1/ and I have tried what was suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2112074/sort-special-json-multilevel) but was unable to make it work.

I have two questions, one: how do I go about accomplishing this, and two: is there a better way to do the sorting?

Comment: Next time please include the relevant code in the question. If jsFiddle goes down (which it sometimes does) your question is incomplete.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, define a compare function:

```js
function compare(el1, el2, index) {
  return el1[index] == el2[index] ? 0 : (el1[index] < el2[index] ? -1 : 1);
}
```

Then, to sort the array on the first column, use this:

```js
array.sort(function(el1,el2){
  return compare(el1, el2, "Functional Category")
});
```

Or, to sort on the first column A-Z, and on the second column Z-A if the first column is equal:

```js
array.sort(function(el1,el2){
  var compared = compare(el1, el2, "Functional Category")
  return compared == 0 ? -compare(el1, el2, "Brand Name") : compared;
});
```

Comment: This works great. I ran into a problem getting it to print but solved that. Seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/Skooljester/agcUk/3/ Thank you very much!

Comment: Yeah, I've used your previous jsfiddle to test it, see http://jsfiddle.net/88HVZ/7/

Answer (score 8):

see below code ....

```
function sortObject(o) {
    var sorted = {},
    key, a = [];

    for (key in o) {
        if (o.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                a.push(key);
        }
    }

    a.sort();

    for (key = 0; key < a.length; key++) {
        sorted[a[key]] = o[a[key]];
    }
    return sorted;
}
```

Does that help?

Comment: Please excuse my inexperience, but in trying to implement the code, it doesn't work out as expected http://jsfiddle.net/Skooljester/WtDTD/1/

Comment: This will break on V8 for numeric keys: http://code.google.com/p/v8/issues/detail?id=164

Comment: @MANISH LANGA, +1 Great function! This would be the correct answer, in my opinion. :-)

Answer (score 6):

The Mozilla developer documentation has a helpful explanation of the sort function. You can provide a function as a parameter that tells the browser how to do the sort.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Some pseudo-code from that link, with the myArray.sort call added and the function name removed:

```
myArray.sort(function(a, b) {
  if (a is less than b by some ordering criterion)
     return -1;
  if (a is greater than b by the ordering criterion)
     return 1;
  // a must be equal to b
  return 0;
});
```

EDIT: It looks like you have a single-element array with an object as the element. Objects are unordered. You have to transform it to an array before it can be sorted. Try this (with the Object.keys and Array.prototype.map functions added via [augment.js](http://augmentjs.com/) for older browsers):

```
var result = Object.keys(myArray[0]).sort().map(function(key) {
    return [key,myArray[0][key]];
});
```

This will give you a sorted, nested array of the form:

```
[["Brand Name","threadless"],
 ["Function Category","T-Shirt"],
 ...
]
```

Comment: I have looked at that but was unable to figure out how to implement it.

Answer (score 2):

Something of this kind might be on help:

```
function (obj) {
   var a = [],x;
   for(x in obj){ 
     if(obj.hasOwnProperty(x)){
         a.push([x,obj[x]]);
     }
   }
   a.sort(function(a,b){ return a[0]>b[0]?1:-1; })
   return a;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your intent is to allow the user to sort the table dynamically, then my approach may be slightly different.

There are plenty of jQuery table sorting plugins. I have had good success with this one: http://tablesorter.com/docs/

Allows multi-column sort, a default sort, wire up to events, etc... etc...

This way you can build your table as you already are, and sorting can be done secondary even before page output.

Comment: That is the correct intent. However, as I am still learning javascript/jQuery I am trying to make it sort without using a plug-in.

Answer (score 0):

This might be helpful for someone in the future if you want to do deep sorting for json properties (where a property value is also a Json object)

```js
function sortObject(o) {
    var sorted = {},
    key, a = [];

    for (key in o) {
        if (o.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                a.push(key);
        }
    }

    a.sort();

    for (key = 0; key < a.length; key++) {
        if(typeof o[a[key]] === 'object'){
            sorted[a[key]] = sortObject(o[a[key]]);
        } else{
            sorted[a[key]] = o[a[key]];
        }
        
    }
    return sorted;
}
```

Comment: Without an actual example, this is not a very helpful answer, which BTW has little to do with the original question. Second, note that object key iteration has no guaranteed order, but see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/5525812/563970. Last, learn about [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries). If you must sort objects, those can simplify your approach quite a bit.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this approach too. Used less variable to save few lines here!!

```
var newArr = [{}]; // just to matching pattern with Que variable here
Object.keys(arr[0]).sort().forEach(s => {
    newArr[0][s] = arr[0][s];
})

console.log(newArr);
```

Output:

```
[{
  "Brand Name": "threadless",
  "Functional Category": "T-Shirt",
  "Has a Graphic": "Yes",
  "How Obtained": "Purchased",
  "How Often Worn": "Monthly",
  "When Obtained": "Last 3 Months",
  "Where It's Made": "India"
}]
```

Comment: That just sorts the keys in 1 item (`arr[0]` is a strong hint here), not multiple items. Also, manually constructing an array from another array should be done using `.map`, not `.forEach` into a new array.